# Almacenar variables en Bash a partir de un resultado en postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, bash, shell-script

Tengo un script Bash en Linux:

```
psql postgresql://postgres:****@****/**** --quiet --no-align --field-separator ' ' -t -c "SELECT * FROM *" | while read -a Datos_Consulta ; do
```

En donde yo almaceno los datos de las variables de la siguiente manera:

```
DATO1=${Datos_Consulta[0]}
DATO2=${Datos_Consulta[1]}
DATO3=${Datos_Consulta[2]}
```

y luego lo muestro asi:

```
echo "DATO 1: $DATO1"
done
```

El ciclo se completa una vez haya recorrido todas las filas.

Hasta acá va todo perfecto, el problema está cuando uno de los datos tiene espacios, por ejemplo si yo tengo:

```
id: 2323
fecha: 29/06/2018
nombre: Juan Perez
```

Me toma el id como [0], la fecha como [1] pero el nombre como [2] y [3] por el espacio... el problema que tengo es que no sé el tamaño fijo o la cantidad de espacio que hay en determinados campos (algunos son descripciones)

¿Hay una forma que me lo tome completo con espacios y todo?

Comment: Cambia el separador creo que es lo más sano

Comment: Sería bueno que proporcionaras todo el script, para que viéramos con todo lujo de detalles qué haces. Sin embargo, lo que comenta @JackNavaRow parece lo más razonable: si pones un delimitador que no esté en el texto que te devuelve postgreSQL seguro que no tendrás este problema.